# Django select_related has no effect

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

The query below should return the most liked posts of the week. As the `select_related()` method should populate `.post` attributes but the query returns a list of dicts instead of model instances.

**Model**

```
class Like(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

**Query**

- Why do i use `.values(...)`?
  to group records: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/aggregation/#values
- Put `select_related()` after `values(..)`?!
  `Cannot call select_related() after .values() or .values_list()`

```
likes = Like.objects.select_related().values('post', 'created').annotate(
  year=ExtractYear('created'),
  week=ExtractWeek('created'),
  yearweek=Concat('year', Value(''), 'week'),
  likes=Count('yearweek'),
).order_by('-likes')[:10]
```

**Output**

```
<QuerySet [{'post': 2, 'likes': 1, ...}, {'post': 3, 'likes': 1, ...}]>
```

I get `AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'post'` when doing `likes[0].post`

Comment: It is `likes[0]['post']`.

Comment: But the `.select_related` does not matter from the moment you work with `.values`, that is one of the (many) reasons, why using `.values(...)` is not a good idea.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Well it won't give me the post record. i don't want the ids.

Comment: no of course not, since once you work with `.values(...)`, the entire thing collapses to simple dictionaries.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem it's a group by query. i have to do `values` before `annotate` to group records.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/aggregation/#values